# Displaying Radius in Meters with Folium

Tags: python, maps, gis, folium

I am having trouble understanding how the radius option works with Folium.

I have the following code:

```
import folium

lat = 40.7787006
lon = -73.9654842

map = folium.Map(location=[lat, lon], zoom_start=20)
folium.Marker([lat, lon]).add_to(map)
folium.CircleMarker([lat, lon],
                    radius=40
                   ).add_to(map)

map
```

I have seen a number of places where it states that `radius=40` should show a 40 meter radius around the marker.

The result of this code is:

[image]

But if I change the zoom to `zoom_start=5` I get a wider view but a circle of the same size.  This is not a 40 meter radius around the point.

[image]

Any idea how this works?  How do I show a 40m radius?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The `radius` option shows the radius around the marker in pixels.  To get the radius in meters, you need to use `Circle` not `CircleMarker`.

```
folium.Circle([lat, lon],
                    radius=40
                   ).add_to(map)
```